# AnyLogic tutorial example is not working for me

Tags: anylogic

I'm new to AnyLogic and Java. I had some errors when I was working the Air Defence System, the example in the tutorial.

The method getY() is undefined for the type OptionList. Air Defense System/Bomber/ToTarget - State
The method getX() is undefined for the type OptionList. Air Defense System/Bomber/ToTarget - State
The method add_bombers(OptionList) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (Building). Air Defense System/Main/startMission - Event

I followed the tutorial step by step, I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMRuR.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbFUN.png

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi Steven, quickly checked the tutorial instructions and there is no mention of OptionLists as far as I can see. This suggests you accidentally created an OptionList, causing all your errors. I hope you tried to run your model after every tutorial step, checking if it works? If so, you know which step caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you flagged an agent to be of type OptionList instead of an actual agent.

Since there are no OptionLists in given tutorial, you probably made a mistake following the instructions. Check in your Projects view if you have any OptionLists and figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I likewise had this issue. The issue was I had not set the target correctly.

In the top left click on the Project, then go to `Bomber > Parameters > target`

here you need to make sure you set the type as `Other > Building`.

P.S I also deleted the Optionlist in the project folder, although I am unsure if this helped.